# Is it possible to load a page in cordova-plugin-inappbrowser plugin on an ios device with a target of '_blank'?

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4, inappbrowser

I am trying to use the inappbrowser cordova plugin to open a webpage. When I supply a target of '_blank' the browser opens but just sits there on a screen that says 'Loading...'. This only happens when running on an ios device; it works fine on android. I am using v3.0.0 of the plugin and running it on ios v11.2.6. If I supply a target of _self or _system then it works, but this is not an option for me.

I have already added the following to my config.xml

```
   <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
```

and I have also added this to my index.html page

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com;">
```

Neither of these make a difference. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Can you share the code when you open InAppBrowser ?

Comment: I am injecting the inAppBrowser into my controller and then calling the create method. I.e. inAppBrowser.create("http://www.google.com", "_blank", {})